# MDI Child Windows overdraw frame toolbar?

Tags: toolbar, mdi

I have write a MDI application with toolbar, but the child window overdraw the frame window's toolbar. Here is the effect, I have to click the left corner to see the toolbar icons.

[image]

I create the toolbar with following code:

```
CToolBar::CToolBar(HINSTANCE hInst, HWND hParent, LPCTSTR lpszWindowName) :
        CWindow(hInst, hParent, lpszWindowName)
{
        INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;

        // Ensure that the common control DLL is loaded.
        icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
        icex.dwICC  = ICC_BAR_CLASSES;
        InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

        lstrcpy(m_szClassName, TOOLBARCLASSNAME);
}

BOOL CToolBar::Create()
{
        //create the toolbar
        m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, (LPCTSTR) NULL,
                WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 0, 0, m_hParent,
                (HMENU) ID_TOOLBAR, m_hInst, NULL);

        //for backword compatibility
        SendMessage(m_hWnd, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM) sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);

        if (m_hWnd == NULL)
                return FALSE;
        return TRUE;
}

BOOL CToolBar::Init()
{
        TBBUTTON tbb[3];
        TBADDBITMAP tbab;

        if (! Create() )
                return FALSE;

        //Add standard toolbar bitmaps
        tbab.hInst = HINST_COMMCTRL;
        tbab.nID = IDB_STD_SMALL_COLOR;
        SendMessage(m_hWnd, TB_ADDBITMAP, 0, (LPARAM)&tbab);

        //Add buttons
        ZeroMemory(tbb, sizeof(tbb));
        tbb[0].iBitmap = STD_CUT;
        tbb[0].idCommand = IDS_CUT;
        tbb[0].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
        tbb[0].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;

        tbb[1].iBitmap = STD_COPY;
        tbb[1].idCommand = IDS_COPY;
        tbb[1].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
        tbb[1].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;

        tbb[2].iBitmap = STD_PASTE;
        tbb[2].idCommand = IDS_PASTE;
        tbb[2].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
        tbb[2].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;

        SendMessage(m_hWnd, TB_ADDBUTTONS, (WPARAM) 3, (LPARAM) (LPTBBUTTON) &tbb);
        ShowWindow(m_hWnd, SW_NORMAL);
        return TRUE;
}
```

I test it with SDI windows, it works well, but after I create the MDICLIENT(client) window, it sucks.

Please help me to work around this peculiar problem.
You COULD get all the source code at https://code.google.com/p/jcyangs-code/source/browse/trunk/com/lib/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle WM_SIZE message of Frame Window.